# Cannot access to my Propel's classes

Tags: php, orm, propel

I have a problem with accessing my Propel's classes.
For example, I try to access the `Livre` class.

My code in index.php is :

```
use biblio\biblio\Livre;
//load Propel's autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$collect = new Livre();
$collect->setNom("Aventure");
$collect->save();
```

And the output error is :

> Fatal error: Class 'biblio\biblio\Livre' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/propel/index.php on line 7

My classe `Livre` is in the folder `biblio/biblio/Livre.php`
With this code, Eclipse finds my `Livre`. But when PHP executes, there is an error.

Somebody have a solution ?

Comment: Could you add the contents of your composer.json file?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to add something like this to your `composer.json` file (obviously modifying this `autoload` data into the entire JSON file, rather than just appending this as-is):

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["biblio/"]
  }
}
```

Without this, `require vendor/autoload.php;` won't include your Propel classes and PHP won't be able to find the namespace/class. Don't forget to run `php composer dump-autoload` from your command line to update the `autoload.php` file.

---

See the [Propel documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#generate-model-classes) for more information:

> After generating the classes, you have to autoload them.

Or, learn more about [Composer's autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and you will get autoloading for free. [...] You can even add your own code to the autoloader by adding an autoload field to composer.json.